# Browser displays wrong color

Tags: html, css, browser, background-color

i want to display a div on my website which has the color rgb(244,209,82). So i defined the color in css, but the browser shows a different color than the one I selected. Instead it's rgb(239, 210, 104)! I've tried it chrome, safari and opera, but the problem appears in every browser.

Here is my code:

```css
#container{
    margin: 5rem;
    background-color: rgb(244,209,82);
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Wrong color</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1 id="title">This is the title</h1>
        <p id="text">This is the text</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here you can see the color i want:
[image with correct color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6z6hJ.png)

This is the color i get: [displayed color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agdAP.png)

I've also tried to use an image with this color, but this was also displayed wrong, so i assume this could be a universal problem with this color and browsers (however, the screenshot above is displayed correctly, unlike the image I used, which consisted only of the color). I've selected the color in Adobe XD, were it was displayed correctly.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try to write !important after the color in css?

Comment: The RGB color from the image is: rgb(250,208,82). https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/jtpogbvd/1/

Comment: Could you please provide all of your css? Is it possible that the color is overridden by another rule? Maybe you can copy-paste your code on codepen and add it on your description? Maybe there is some js changing it?

Comment: Sounds more like your monitor needs calibrating.

Comment: Do you extract the info about the color code from the dev tools?

Comment: @Paulie_D - The exact opposite is the case. The monitor is rendering the embedded color profile too well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture has an embedded color profile. Depending on your operating system and browser the profile can be rendered or not. The better your screen, the bigger is the chance that you see the difference.

It is best practice to not user color-profiles on the interweb at all, except for very rare and specific cases. strip the profile out of the image and you will be fine. you will reach the best compatibility by using rgb or srgb.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try: 
background-color: #fad12a; 
or 
background-color: rgba(250,209,42,1);

Comment: this answer only applies to browsers that can handle the embedded color profile in the picture. so this will work for some viewers, but not for all.